Singularities of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}$

Determine singularities and classified them into removable singularities, poles, and essential singularities of
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}$$


After some calculation that if needed I can post I find that some singularities are complex numbers with null imaginary part and real part equals to $a = 1-\frac{1}{2k+1}, k \in \Bbb Z$, I call them $z_k$.
Since
$$\frac{d}{dz}\bigg[\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)\bigg]_{z_k} \ne 0, k\ne -1 $$
I conclude that these are 1-poles and I can easily work out residues. Now I have a feeling that for $z=0$ we have a $2$-pole since $\frac{1}{z}$ has a simple pole and $\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-0)}\big)=0$, but I'm not able to formalize this reasoning.
Last but not least the biggest headache of them all $z=1$, the only approach I'm familiar with is trying to express in Laurent series and
$$\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{((z-1)+1)\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}\\
&= \color{red}{\frac{1}{((z-1)+1)}}\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}}
\end{align*}$$
the red part is a geometric series and blue part could be express in term of cosine series but I'm not able to go forward from there.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit I know that MathSE policy is to ask just one question so I hope to be forgiven and in case I'll post a separate question but I find that trying to evaluate the residue in $z=0$ with
$$\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\bigg (\frac{d}{dz}\bigg)^{k-1}\big(z^kf_k(z)\big)(0)$$
is very tricky since there's a zero in the denominator, this means that I should proceed via Laurent expansion?

What do you mean by the nature of the singularities? Do you mean the classification into removable  singularities, poles, and essential singularities?

Hint: for the pole to be of order $2$ you'll need that $\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-0)}\big)=0$ to be a zero of order $1$, which means that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z}\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)$ exists and is not $0$. Can you prove that?

$z=1$ is not an isolated singularity, because it is the limit of the poles $1 - 1/(2k+1)$ as $k \to +\infty$ or $-\infty$.  That's all you have to say about it. So it shouldn't be a headache at all.

@JoséCarlosSantos exactly that

Then, as @RobertIsrael explained, there is no answer, since that classification does not apply to your case.

@jjagmath I think that I can prove your limit cause is the derivative in $z=0$ so I can recycle some calculation that I've done before.
